# PostgreSQL / PostGIS Export Data Structure

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using the following SQL command to export data from a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.

```
COPY (SELECT a.fname,a.lname,a.mailing_address,a.mailing_city,a.mailing_state,a.mailing_zip,a.property_name,a.property_address,a.property_city,a.property_state,a.property_zip,
b.*
FROM "property_owners" a, "property_sold" b
WHERE (a.property_name ~* b.sold_name)
OR ST_Distance_Sphere(a.geom2,b.geom2,)<=80450)

TO 'C:\Users\Desktop\test\export20.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

The property_owners table contains names, mailing addresses and property information that will be used for a mail merge. The property_sold table contains recently sold properties and their address and are matched against the property_owners table based on the SQL query above.

As you can imagine, there are situations where more than one property_sold is a match for a row in the property_owners table. This results in the name and mailing addresses being repeated for how ever many matches there are. Since I'm the data for a mail merge it's not an ideal output. Ideally, the data would be output to contain the property_owners information and all matches from property_sold on the same line.

What changes do I need to make to my query to accomplish this? Or, would I be better off trying to figure out someway to manipulate the data through excel?

Thanks!

Comment: you definitely don't need excell. Do you only want the property name or do you want all the columns from the properties sold table? If you want all, please post the table structures

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for your help and sorry for the delay in responding. I would need all of the columns from the property sold table. The columns are sold_name, sold_address, sold_city, sold_state, sold_zip, sale_price and date_sold